# Tricentis Tosca - Integrating with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, tosca

Trying to integrate my `C#` `Selenium WebDriver Script` with `Tosca` and running into the following error while trying to execute the script.

> Skipped loading assembly SeleniumProject because it references an unsupported version of the nunit.framework, 3.0.5797.27534

I tried different Versions of nunit but getting the same Error.

Does any one got the same error?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the last nunit version supported is 2.6.4.
You seem to be using version 3 of the framework, which is unsupported.